# Titanium File Error when CommonJS modules too large?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, titanium, commonjs

In my Titanium App, when my included CommonJS modules have over a certain number of methods defined, I get File Error when building the app, how very strange. Is that maybe because it's taking up too much memory?

Any ideas anybody?

**Script Error = Result of expression 'Ti.UI.createTab' [40] is not a function. (unknown file)**

Comment: Did you remove the previous build?

Comment: how large are you commonJS modules? I would rethink the architecture if they are that big. break them up in to logical modules

Comment: possible duplicate of [The system cannot find the file specified "classes.dex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002284/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-classes-dex)