# The system cannot find the file specified "classes.dex"

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have developed android module project and deployed in Titanium Project. When I run the Titanium Project am getting this err frequently

```
    [INFO] logfile = C:\ws\Testw2\build.log
    [INFO] Building Testw2 for Android ... one moment
    [INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.0.0 (12/12/12 18:49 a5894b3)
    [INFO] Fastdev server running, deploying in Fastdev mode
    [INFO] Copying CommonJS modules...
    [INFO] Copying project resources..
    [INFO] Tiapp.xml unchanged, skipping class generation
    [INFO] Force including all modules...
    [INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
    [INFO] Compiling localization files
    [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
    [ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
    [ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2376, in <module>
    [ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 2192, in build_and_run
    [ERROR]     launched, launch_failed = self.package_and_deploy()
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1688, in package_and_deploy
    [ERROR]     unsigned_apk = self.create_unsigned_apk(ap_)
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.0.GA\android\builder.py", line 1559, in create_unsigned_apk
    [ERROR]     apk_zip.write(self.classes_dex, 'classes.dex')
    [ERROR]   File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1031, in write
    [ERROR]     st = os.stat(filename)
    [ERROR] WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\ws\\Testw2\\build\\android\\bin\\classes.dex'
```

After manully removed build folder and run, I am getting the bellow err

```
    [INFO] logfile = C:\ws\Testw2\build.log
    [INFO] Building Testw2 for Android ... one moment
    [INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.0.0 (12/12/12 18:49 a5894b3)
    [INFO] Fastdev server running, deploying in Fastdev mode
    [INFO] Copying CommonJS modules...
    [INFO] Copying project resources..
    [INFO] Detected change in tiapp.xml, or assets deleted. Forcing full re-build...
    [INFO] Force including all modules...
    [INFO] Force including all modules...
    [INFO] Compiling Javascript Resources ...
    [INFO] Compiling localization files
    [INFO] Compiling Android Resources... This could take some time
    [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    [ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:301)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    [ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody;
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:301)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    [ERROR]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    [ERROR] 2 errors; aborting
    [ERROR] System Error while compiling Android classes.dex
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the build folder (C:\\ws\\Testw2\\build) manually and build then? Did you install Android NDK which is possibly needed for module development?

Comment: Ya I have set the enviroinment for module developement with SDK and NDK and I got the .zip file. After that I have added .zip file in Titanium Project. Here only I am getting the err. Also I manulally removed biuld folder and run. getting same result

Comment: you mean module as zip file? That's wrong. You need to put the content of that zip folder into the project. Here's how to do this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Using_Titanium_Modules-section-30083141_UsingTitaniumModules-InstallingModules

Comment: nope.. not module as a zip file. build.xml --> ant build --> dist folder module-android-1.zip

Comment: yes and you need to put the content of this package into your project. not the zip file. is this a log file of building your app or your module?

Comment: I am able to build module project.. getting err in app when deploying in emulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24898/discussion-between-selvam-r-and-mr-vvoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others having the same or similar issue:

> [ERROR] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>
> [ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;

means that you added a library to your module which is also provided by Android or Titanium itself. Simply remove these additional libraries and try to recompile everything.

Additional information on using external libs in a titanium module are available here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/11/integrating-an-external-library-in-an-android-module.html